# What sort of loop structure to compare checkbox matrix with Google Maps markers?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, loops, comparison

I'm trying to build a map of trails around my town.

I'm using an XML file to hold all the trail data. For each marker, I have categories like "surface," "difficulty," "uses," etc.

I have seen many examples of Google Maps that use checkboxes to show markers by category. However these examples are usually very simple: maybe three different checkboxes.

What's different on my end is that I have multiple categories, and within each category there are several possible values. So, a particular trail might have "use" values of "hiking," "biking," "jogging," and "equestrian" because all are allowed.

What I want is for the map to display only markers that match ALL the values that are checked (rather than ANY).

**I took a hack at this. You can see the result here**: http://www.joshrenaud.com/pd/trails_withcheckboxes4.html

(I should point out there is a bug where despite only one category being checked on load, all markers display anyway.)

It doesn't work.

I am pretty new to Javascript, so I am sure I have done something totally wrong, but I can't figure out what.

My specific questions:

1. Does anyone see anything glaringly obvious that is keeping my second example from working?
2. If not, could someone just suggest what sort of loop structure I would need to build to compare the several arrays of checkboxes with the several arrays of values on any given marker?

Here is some of the relevant code, although you can just view source on the examples above to see the whole thing:

```
function createMarker(point,surface,difficulty,use,html) {
    var marker = new GMarker(point,GIcon);
    marker.mysurface = surface;
    marker.mydifficulty = difficulty;
    marker.myuse = use;
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    return marker;
}

function show() {
    hide();

    var surfaceChecked = [];
    var difficultyChecked = [];
    var useChecked = [];
    var j=0;

    // okay, let's run through the checkbox elements and make arrays to serve as holders of any values the user has checked.
    for (i=0; i<surfaceArray.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById('surface'+surfaceArray[i]).checked == true) {
            surfaceChecked[j] = surfaceArray[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    j=0;
    for (i=0; i<difficultyArray.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById('difficulty'+difficultyArray[i]).checked == true) {
            difficultyChecked[j] = difficultyArray[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    j=0;
    for (i=0; i<useArray.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById('use'+useArray[i]).checked == true) {
            useChecked[j] = useArray[i];
            j++;
        }
    }


    //now that we have our 'xxxChecked' holders, it's time to go through all the markers and see which to show.

    for (var k=0; k<gmarkers.length; k++) { // this loop runs thru all markers
        var surfaceMatches = [];
        var difficultyMatches = [];
        var useMatches = [];
        var surfaceOK = false;
        var difficultyOK = false;
        var useOK = false;

        for (var l=0; l<surfaceChecked.length; l++) { // this loops runs through all checked Surface categories
            for (var m=0; m<gmarkers[k].mysurface.length; m++) { // this loops through all surfaces on the marker
                if (gmarkers[k].mysurface[m].childNodes[0].nodeValue == surfaceChecked[l]) {
                    surfaceMatches[l] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        for (l=0; l<difficultyChecked.length; l++) { // this loops runs through all checked Difficulty categories
            for (m=0; m<gmarkers[k].mydifficulty.length; m++) { // this loops through all difficulties on the marker
                if (gmarkers[k].mydifficulty[m].childNodes[0].nodeValue == difficultyChecked[l]) {
                    difficultyMatches[l] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        for (l=0; l<useChecked.length; l++) { // this loops runs through all checked Use categories
            for (m=0; m<gmarkers[k].myuse.length; m++) { // this loops through all uses on the marker
                if (gmarkers[k].myuse[m].childNodes[0].nodeValue == useChecked[l]) {
                    useMatches[l] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        // now it's time to loop thru the Match arrays and make sure they are all completely true.
        for (m=0; m<surfaceMatches.length; m++) {
            if (surfaceMatches[m] == true) { surfaceOK = true; }
            else if (surfaceMatches[m] == false) {surfaceOK = false; break; }
        }
        for (m=0; m<difficultyMatches.length; m++) {
            if (difficultyMatches[m] == true) { difficultyOK = true; }
            else if (difficultyMatches[m] == false) {difficultyOK = false; break; }
        }
        for (m=0; m<useMatches.length; m++) {
            if (useMatches[m] == true) { useOK = true; }
            else if (useMatches[m] == false) {useOK = false; break; }
        }
        // And finally, if each of the three OK's is true, then let's show the marker.
        if ((surfaceOK == true) && (difficultyOK == true) && (useOK == true)) {
            gmarkers[i].show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, nobody responded, but after a few days I solved my own problem. Basically the loop structure I came up with *was* correct. But there were a few missing pieces.

I added break statements to a couple of the if statements. Because each marker could have several values for a given category, it might loop through once and find a match and set the "surfaceMatches" flag to true. But then it would loop through again and check the next value in the category, find it wasn't a match, and set the flag to false. So putting in the break caused the for loop to stop after a category match.

Also, at the end I had gmarkers[i].show(); . It should have been gmarkers[k].show().

And lastly, I realized that when I set up my "category OK" flags, I set them all to false. This was okay, except that what if the user left a particular category blank? Then the matching loops would never be executed, and the flags would remain false. So I added some statements to check if a category didn't have any values checked, then set the OK flag to true, like this:

if (surfaceChecked.length < 1) { surfaceOK = true; }

If you want to see the code in action, go here: http://www.joshrenaud.com/pd/trails_withcheckboxes5.html

Probably nobody cares about any of that. But this might be helpful:

As a javascript novice, I did come across a debugging tool that made all the difference for me and helped me find my mistakes: www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/javascript_debugging_for_beginners/

Using those log(); statements was VERY handy, although the output got pretty long with all the nested loops in my javascript.

Comment: i use "Save link as.." to save your link
http://www.joshrenaud.com/pd/trails_withcheckboxes5.html
this single html file onto my Desktop but when I open it from my browser, all the markers didn't show.
any reason?

Comment: It's a security issue. The map requests an XML file, and most browsers won't let you do it locally.